# How to filter this week from this month in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, filter, filtering

I have two functions one finds this week's files and the other one finds this month's files. I want to extract/filter this week's files from this month's files.

```
filterThisWeek(files) {
      const firstDayOfWeek = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - new Date().getDay()));
      return this.filterToday(files).filter((f) => {
        return f.date >= firstDayOfWeek;
      });
    },
filterThisMonth(files) {
      const today = new Date();
      return files.filter((f) => {
        return (
          new Date(f.date).getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
          new Date(f.date).getFullYear() === today.getFullYear()
        );
      });
```

using filterThisWeek function I want to extract this week's files from this month. So filterThisMonth function should find this month's files except this week's files. I want to do it in most efficient way but I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating functions `getStartOfWeek()` and `getStartOfMonth()` to establish the required date thresholds.

We'd then use these to create the desired limits in the filter functions `filterThisWeek()` and `filterThisMonth()`.

filterThisWeek() should return any files with a date greater than or equal to the start of the week while filterThisMonth() should return any files with a date greater than or equal to the start of the month and less then the start of the week;

```js
function getStartOfWeek(date) {
    const dt = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
    const offset = dt.getDate() - (dt.getDay() === 0 ? 6: dt.getDay() - 1);
    return new Date(dt.setDate(offset));
}

function getStartOfMonth(date) {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1)
}

function filterThisWeek(files, referenceDate = new Date()) {
    const lowerThreshold = getStartOfWeek(referenceDate);
    return files.filter(file => file.date >= lowerThreshold);
}

function filterThisMonth(files, referenceDate = new Date()) {
    const lowerThreshold = getStartOfMonth(referenceDate);
    const upperThreshold = getStartOfWeek(referenceDate);
    return files.filter(file => file.date >= lowerThreshold && file.date < upperThreshold);
}

function formatFile(file) {
    return `${file.date.toLocaleDateString('sv')}`;
}

const testFiles = Array.from( { length: 14 }, (v, k) => { 
    return { date: new Date(Date.now() - k*86400*1000)};
})

console.log('This weeks files:', filterThisWeek(testFiles).map(formatFile));
console.log('This months files:', filterThisMonth(testFiles).map(formatFile));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was wondering if I can extract/filter thisMonth's documents directly using thisWeek function?

Comment: So the thisWeek function should return both this months files and this weeks files?